# Flexbox for mobile border width of 100%

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I'm using flexbox for my navigation and I can't seem to get my borders to work right for my media query specified for column wrap.

I want the borders to stretch across the device width completely, for example I want the border all the way from the left to all the way on the right on the device, and I want each a element to take up one 'row' on the device but currently the borders only stretch half way and some of the `li` elements are sharing a row when others are not and I'm not too sure why. Even when I make `a` to display block, it's not working. I also tried making flex basis 100% for the a elements.

**Edit:** I think I figured it out for the positioning. I made the `#nav ul`. not just `#nav` column wrap. However, I'm still experiencing the border problem unfortunately.

```css
#nav {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -moz-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-flex-flow: row wrap;
  margin: 0;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  background-color: orange;
}
#nav li a {
  color: white;
  margin: 15px;
  padding: 5px;
  display: block;
  ;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 24px;
  font-family: courier;
}
#nav li {
  list-style: none;
}
#nav ul {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -moz-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-flex-flow: row wrap;
  margin: 0;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
@media all and(max-width: 800px) {
  #nav {
    justify-content: space-around;
  }
}
@media all and (max-width: 500px) {
  #nav {
    flex-flow: column wrap;
    padding: 5px;
  }
  #nav li a {
    flex: 1 100%;
    display: block;
    padding: 5px;
    border-top: 1px solid black;
    border-bottom: 1px solid black;
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="nav">
  <ul>
    <li> <a href="#">Calendar </a></li>
    <li> <a href="#">Events </a></li>
    <li> <a href="#">Hours </a></li>
    <li> <a href="#">Contact </a></li>
    <li> <a href="#">About </a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to reset the default padding on `ul` element.

```
ul {
  padding-left: 0;
}
```

also reset the default margin on `body` if needed.

```
body {
  margin: 0;
}
```

For the flexbox part, you should set `display: flex;` on `#nav ul`, rather than `#nav`. You don't need to set any style on `#nav` actually. If you want the each `li` to take 100% width in the media query, you can set flex item to `flex: 1 1 100%;`, working example in the fiddle below.

```css
@media all and (max-width: 500px) {
  #nav li {
    flex: 1 1 100%;
    padding: 5px;
    border-top: 1px solid black;
    border-bottom: 1px solid black;
  }
}
```

**[jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/02y7t11v/)**